Would a question about the motives/ purposes of OT be on-topic here?
Two weeks ago, my father had a heart attack leading to multiple by-pass surgery.  All things considered, aside from having nothing happen at all, what has happened is possibly the best thing that could have happened, and his recovery is proceeding great.
Still, he will be spending the next month or so in a rehab center, getting round-the-clock nursing care, as well as undergoing physical and occupational therapy, before being able to return to his home.
What he has described to me regarding the OT is what I would call Kindergarten Arts and Crafts- making designs out of felt pieces, for example.  He himself has said he feels like the OT treats him like he is 4, not 84.
What he needs is to ensure he is able to shower, shave, shine, and that other sh-word, to cook an egg on the stove, wash the dishes, and so on.  I am insanely curious as to how the one ultimately relates to the other.
Would this be the right place to ask?  If so, any tips on how to phrase the question, and the proper tags?

My opinion, no. I do not see what this has to do with "a question and answer site for researchers, academics, students, and enthusiasts needing expert answers to advanced questions in the "cognitive sciences": I.e., cognitive science, psychology, neuroscience, and psychiatry. ".

Might be appropriate on [health.se], you can ask on their meta.

Question asked on Health: http://health.stackexchange.com/q/5155/3205.  Thank you.
